# ReactJS with map function does not display all array elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have code which populates an array of objects.  The code looks like this:

```
renderMultiplePEO = () => {

    let currentComponent = this;

    var localData = {
        redirect: true,
        familyID: "",
        planID: "",
        location: '',
        memberID: "",
        PIN: ""
    }

    localData = currentComponent.state.passData;
    var PEOCount = localData.location;
    var PEOList = currentComponent.state.PEOList;

    var locationArray = [];
    var displacement = -56;

    for (var counter=0;counter<PEOCount;counter++) {
        var locationObject = {
            counter: 0,
            location: '',
            locationStatus: '',
            locationName: ''
        }
        displacement=displacement+56;
        locationObject.location = PEOList.substr(displacement+10,5);
        locationObject.locationStatus = PEOList.substr(displacement+15,1);
        locationObject.locationName = PEOList.substr(displacement+16,40);
        if (locationObject.locationStatus == "A") {
            locationObject.counter = counter + 1;
            locationArray[counter] = locationObject;
        }
    }

    console.log("location array 0: ", locationArray[0]);
    console.log("location array 1: ", locationArray[1]);
    console.log("location array 2: ", locationArray[2]);

    return ( locationArray.map( item => (
        <div className="FullBackground">   
            <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12 text-left text_14">
                        <label id="lblName">{item.location} - {item.locationName}</label>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>      
        </div>
    )))
}
```

The value of currentComponent.state.passData.location is 2

The value of currentComponent.state.PEOList is

```
855100001 00001AApple Inc. 1                            855100001900003AGoogle Inc. 3
```

renderMultiplePEO is called from the general render() section with this code:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.passData.redirect === "Multiple PEO") {  
        var PEOCount = this.state.passData.location;
        return (
            <div className="FullBackground">   
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-12 text-left text_16">
                            <label>We see that you are participating in {PEOCount} locations. Please select the location you would like to access.</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
                </div>  
                <div>
                    {this.renderMultiplePEO()} 
                </div>    
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

When I run the application, this is what is generated to the console and to the output window:

[image]

When you look at the console, you can see that I am populating locationArray [0] and locationArray[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EwSp.jpg) with data.

My question is why does the map function only render 1 element of the locationArray?

Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: inside your map function can you console.log(item) and then screenshot that log. i think that will get us closer to the answer

Comment: are you sure this is not a css/html problem. maybe one element is overlaying over the second.

Comment: Why you are not setting key? https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

Comment: I suspect @ehab is correct. Can you check the DOM to see if the second element isn't there? Even if you aren't setting a key, it should render the component in your local

Comment: Might want to try moving your map inside the container divs, right above `<div className="row">`

Comment: @ehab is correct, it was a css issue.  I removed the <div className="FullBackground"></div> from within the map and the second item shows up.  Theres hours of my life wasted on stupid errors.  Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

where are you calling `renderMultiplePEO`? for me it seems that you're trying to trust in implicit binding of this, but you're actually using an arrow function which does the binding for you and which one you cannot change or modify

Comment: renderMultiplePEO() is called from the general render().  I have modified my question to show the code that calls renderMultiplePEO().  Thanks.